# How to use "actors" in python bdd scenarios?

Tags: python, bdd, actor, python-behave

I would like to create "actors" for my bbd scenarios, is there any simple way to use "actors" in tests written in Python using behave? I've found out Pykka which is a Python implementation of the actor model, but how can I connect behave with Pykka?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: To be honest I just had a look at Pykka

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend Thespian actors for Python instead of Pykka for a much more complete and feature-full implementation (http://thespianpy.com, disclaimer: I am the author of that package).

Using Thespian, you could have a test like:

```
Scenario something
   Given a running actor system
     ...
    Then it completes successfully
```

And in your implementation

```
@given('a running actor system')
def step_impl(context):
    ActorSystem('simpleSystemBase')

@then('it completes successfully')
def step_impl(context):
    asys = ActorSystem()
    asys.createActor(TestActor)
    response = asys.ask(testActor, 'test data', 5)
    assert response == 'data is valid'

class TestActor(Actor):
    def receieveMessage(self, msg, sender):
        if msg == 'test data':
            self.send(sender, 'data is valid')

    def after_all(context):
        ActorSystem().shutdown()
```

This will allow individual tests to access actors, and you can also increase parallelism using other actor system bases:

```
@given('a running multi-process actor system')
def step_impl(context):
    ActorSystem('multiprocTCPBase')
```

Unfortunately, based on a quick review of behave, the core runner is not extensible, so behave itself will probably run your tests serially; if there was a way to run each test in a separate actor that would further increase concurrency beyond what behave currently supports.